# GROUP BY with SUM without removing empty (null) values

Tags: sql, group-by, querydsl, sql-function

TABLES:

**Players**

```
player_no   | transaction_id
----------------------------
1           | 11
2           | 22
3           | (null)
1           | 33
```

**Transactions**

```
id            | value   |
-----------------------
11            | 5
22            | 10
33            | 2
```

My goal is to fetch all data, maintaining all the players, even with `null` values in following query:

```
SELECT p.player_no, COUNT(p.player_no), SUM(t.value) FROM Players p 
INNER JOIN Transactions t ON p.transaction_id = t.id 
GROUP BY p.player_no
```

nevertheless results omit null value, example:

```
player_no | count  | sum
------------------------
1         | 2      |  7
2         | 1      |  10
```

What I would like to have is mention about the empty value:

```
player_no | count  | sum
------------------------
1         | 2      |  7
2         | 1      |  10
3         | 0      |  0
```

What do I miss here?
Actually I use QueryDSL for that, but translated example into pure SQL since it behaves in the same manner.

Comment: So there is no record in the Transactions table but you want it returned from the player table anyway?  If so change your inner join to left join (you may have to change your sum to do a isnull check sum(IsNull(t.value, 0)))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using `LEFT JOIN` and `coalesce` function

```
SELECT p.player_no, COUNT(p.player_no), coalesce(SUM(t.value),0) 
FROM Players p 
LEFT JOIN Transactions t ON p.transaction_id = t.id 
GROUP BY p.player_no
```

Comment: COUNT(p.player_no) is just the same as count(*) here

Comment: @paparazzo yes.you are right.I think  can also  write `COUNT(1)` :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your JOIN to a LEFT JOIN, then add IFNULL(value, 0) in your SUM()

Answer (score 2):

left join keeps all the rows in the left table

```
SELECT p.player_no
     , COUNT(*) as count
     , SUM(isnull(t.value,0)) 
FROM Players p 
LEFT JOIN Transactions t 
       ON p.transaction_id = t.id 
GROUP BY p.player_no
```

You might be looking for `count(t.value)` rather than `count(*)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm just offering this so you have a correct answer:

```
SELECT p.player_no, COUNT(t.id) as [count], COALESCE(SUM(t.value), 0) as [sum]
FROM Players p LEFT JOIN
     Transactions t
     ON p.transaction_id = t.id 
GROUP BY p.player_no;
```

You need to pay attention to the aggregation functions as well as the `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This:

```
SELECT P.player_no,
   COUNT(*) as count,
   SUM(isnull(T.value,0)) 
FROM Players P 
LEFT JOIN Transactions T 
   ON P.transaction_id = T.id 
GROUP BY P.player_no
```

Hope this helps.